# Google Directions API and display the results using MapKit on iOS 6?

Tags: google-maps

I'd like to use the Google Directions API on iOS 6 but I'm concerned about Sections 10.1.1g in the Maps API Terms of Service, which states that content must be displayed exclusively on a Google map. Am I allowed to use the Google Directions API and display the results using MapKit on iOS 6?